# How do I issue a role when entering a command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need that when entering a command, a certain role is given to the person who entered it. I have a code, but it works if you enter a command and a nickname (.command @nickname), I need to make it work just when you enter a command (.command). How can I redo the code to make it work?

```
@client.command(pass_context = True )
@commands.has_role("role1234")
async def command (ctx, author: discord.Member):
    role0 = ctx.guild.get_role(981971100898582539) 
    role1 = ctx.guild.get_role(981594840879988807)
    role3 = ctx.guild.get_role(981971134893395990) 
    role2 = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id = 981971065486057492)
    if role2 in author.roles:
        await ctx.channel.purge( limit = 1000)
        await ctx.author.add_roles(role3)
        await ctx.author.remove_roles(role1)
        await ctx.author.remove_roles(role2)
        await ctx.author.remove_roles(role0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *[...] but it works if you enter a command and a nickname (.command @nickname), I need to make it work just when you enter a command*

I understand perfectly. So, do you know how you can get the `author` as a `discord.Member` object without passing it as an argument to the command?

```
async def command(ctx):
    author = ctx.author # Then you can use this variable in the whole scope of the function
```

So, in your case, the only thing to change except for the prototype of the function is this line:

```
if role2 in author.roles:
```

That should become:

```
if role2 in ctx.author.roles:
```

Comment: I replaced it, but it still gives an error when entering the command
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: author is a required argument that is missing.

Comment: For sure, you **must** remove the argument from the prototype as suggested in the first code snippet.